# Is there a better way to cast objects in c# in order to avoid repetitive IsType Get AsType pattern?

Tags: c#, casting, code-cleanup

We have a lot of this kind of code

```
 if(object is ConcreteType))
{
object = object as ConcreteType;
}
else if(object as ConcreteType2))
{
object = object as ConcreteType2;
}
```

Is there a better way to write this kind of code to avoid repetition?

Comment: This might be a good question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since you have working code.

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code? Depending on what the types look like and how you're using them, maybe interfaces, generics, or reflection could simplify things.

Comment: What do you do with these objects? Surely you could implement a common interface?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

```
IMyInterface myInterface = (IMyInterface) object;
//...
myInterace.DoTheWork1WhichWasDifferentInTheSpecificObjects();
myInterace.DoTheWork2WhichWasDifferentInTheSpecificObjects();
//...
```

Comment: A remark is in order here: your answer implicitly assumes that OP authored both `ContreteType` and `ConcreteType2`, which in general is often not the case.

Comment: @Grx70 Then he can use the adapter pattern to create the required polymorphism by wrapping the types he doesn't control with ones that he does.

Comment: @Servy True, but that's not always possible. For instance, if you receive data through drag'n'drop, and you don't control the source of the data, you'd have to wrap the received object on the spot, which would ultimately lead to determining the object's type anyway...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
Ignore my answer.  It is flawed.   Use Andrej's answer below about interfaces.  You could also use inherited classes, but you won't need my ugly line with the `??` operator.

I guess I haven't had enough coffee yet.

**Original answer below**

If they form an object hierarchy as so:

```
    class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }

    class C : B
    {

    }
```

You can do something like this:

```
A y = new C();
var x = y as C ?? y as B ?? y as A;
```

This will get the most specific class.  If you need to take different action depending on type, then you should have a virtual method in A that is overridden in the other two.

If my assumptions on what you are doing is wrong, then you should re-think your architecture.

Comment: I don't believe that will work with `var`. It's not known at compile time.

Comment: Well, it will "work", but `var` will be `A`, regardless of the concrete type of `y`. It does exactly the same thing as `var x = y as A;`.

Comment: @hvd By "work" you mean "compile".  It doesn't actually *work*.

Comment: @DavidCrowell You could just delete the whole thing and the program would compile.  Compiling alone doesn't mean a program will work.